# Prevent wiping data after stopping firebase simulation on localhost

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

tanx to google , firebase can deploy on localhost for testing. afer stoping simulation all of the states are going to reset and database is wiping out too.

I need to know how to avoid from losing this data and configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Cloud Firestore you can [import data to and export data from](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#export_and_import_emulator_data) the emulator suite. For other emulated products such functionality does not (yet) exist, so you will have to ensure you can re-initialize the data in your application code.

Comment: you mean something like seeders for initializing data?